# Objects inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am looking for a solution how I can access objects in an object.
I am making a game, where the different loots are all objects and the enemies are a different object - like this:

```
item.ingredient.feather.birdfeather //item object
enemy.animal.badger //enemy object
```

Now I want the enemy object have a loot property, where all the possible loot is noted in. This is how the object (and many more, of course) is written in my code:

```
var enemy = {
  animal: {
    badger: {
      loot: [item.ingredient.skin.badgerskin, item.ingredient.teeth.badgerteeth],
      health: 50,
      etc: "lala"
    }
  }
}
```

But for the array of objects in my loot object it always shows me the error
"Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined".

Is there a possibility I can write objects in arrays in a different object variable? Thank you!

EDIT:

item is defined, but in another js file.

```
var item = {
  ingredient: {
    feather: {
      birdfeather: {
        name: "feathers"
      },

      longfeather: {
        name: "long feathers"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Still am wondering about the mistake

Comment: Where is `item` defined?

Comment: Well that error makes me wonder where/how you are declaring item

Comment: You can use a `for` loop to loop over the properties of an object. But your problem is unrelated to that -- the problem is that you don't have a variable containing the object.

Comment: what is `item.ingredient.feather.birdfeather`??

Comment: See in my edit - thanks for the help!

Comment: make sure that the script containg the items declaration is included/executed first before the script that uses it (i.e. the enemy decalaration).

Answer (score 1):

There nothing wrong with your `enemy` object declaration code.
All it needs is the proper declaration of the `item` object.
For example:

```
var item = {
  ingredient: {
    skin: {
      badgerskin: {
        id: "badgerskin",
        name: "Badger Skin",
        etc: 30
      }
    },
    teeth: {
      badgerteeth: {
        id: "badgerteeth",
        name: "Badger Teeth",
        etc: 80
      }
    }
  }
}

var enemy = {
  animal: {
    badger: {
      loot: [item.ingredient.skin.badgerskin, item.ingredient.teeth.badgerteeth],
      health: 50,
      etc: "lala"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See my edit, the item is actually declared, but in another file - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself. Because the two objects were created in two different js files. I had to change the order in the html file in which the scripts were called. Sorry for the trouble and thank you for the answers